# XSD Pattern Restriction - Alternation with forward slash

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I have to create a XSD file. A complex type of mine contains a SimplyType with base xs:string and I would like to give it the following pattern restriction:

```
[X|X/R|X/L]
```

So my intention is to allow either `X`, `X/R` or `X/L`.

When trying to verify a xml against this schema XMLSpy tells me that only `X`, `R`, `L` or `/` is allowed. But not the expected combination.

What am I doing wrong. According to my research a `/` does not need a escape character.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use `X|X/R|X/L`, without brackets. Right, no need to escape `/`, it is not a special char.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your pattern is failing is that by using [Character Classes or Character Sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[ ]`), you're specifying that any of the listed characters are acceptable -- not what you want.

You are right as for the forward slash: it is not a special regex metacharacter in any regex flavor, just sometimes it is used as a regex delimiter in flavors that allow *regex literal* notations (like `/^abc$/`).

So, all you need to use is

```
<xs:pattern value="X|X/R|X/L"/>
```

Or less verbose with `[RL]` (the character class matching either `R` or `L`) instead of repeating the last two values:

```
<xs:pattern value="X|X/[RL]"/>
```

Or even

```
<xs:pattern value="X(/[RL])?"/>
```

Here, `X` is matched, then `/R` or `/L` are matched 1 or  0 times, i.e.  optionally.

XSD patterns are always  anchored by default (=must match the whole string), so you should not add any `^` or `$` at the start/end.

---

Here is a full supporting sample XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
  <xsd:element name="r">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> 
        <xsd:pattern value="X|X/R|X/L"/> 
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: @kjhughes I believe OP does not need that sample, the only problem is with the regex, but it might  be helpful for the total beginners who do not know how to use the regex with the XML Schema.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain to me when to use those [ ] brackets?

Comment: @mrabc Please read [Character Classes or Character Sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), it explains it in great detail. `[abc]` matches `a`, or `b` or `c`. `[^abc]` matches `z`, `/`, ``\``, `?`, `Ч`, any char other than `a` and `b` and `c`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:  Often original posters and future readers appreciate having the full XSD context.   And, actually, from my original answer, I should have also copied my direct statement regarding the crux of OP's problem:   `[  ]` specifies a character class, not a generic grouping, and eliminating it was the key change OP had to make.  OP's recent comment makes it clear that such guidance was needed.    Answer updated.